# How to set multiple selected value of listbox on onchange event of parent dropdownlist in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

my requirement when selectindexchanged on ddl_fvr ,value of ddl_fvr ddl must be selected in  ddl_customer listbox.i only want to do in javascript.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_fvr" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  >
<asp:ListItem Text="a" Value="ezhisai,raja" />
<asp:ListItem Text="b" Value="devi,kumar,sith" />
<asp:ListItem Text="c" Value="bala,raja" />
<asp:ListItem Text="d" Value="ezhisai,kumar,devi" />
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:ListBox ID="ddl_customer" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" style="width:300px"    >
<asp:ListItem Text="ezhisai" Value="ezhisai" />
<asp:ListItem Text="raja" Value="raja" />
<asp:ListItem Text="devi" Value="devi" />
<asp:ListItem Text="kumar" Value="kumar" />
<asp:ListItem Text="sith" Value="sith" />
<asp:ListItem Text="bala" Value="bala" />
</asp:ListBox>


 window.onload = function () {

    var queue = document.getElementById("<%=ddl_fvr.ClientID%>");
    queue.onchange = function () {
        var queuval = queue.value;
        var getSUBqueue = queuval.substring(0, queuval.length-1);
        $.each(getSUBqueue.split(","), function (i, e) {
            $("#ddl_customer option[value='" + e + "']").prop("selected", true);
        });
    };
}
```

i tried above code but not worked

Comment: Have you tried any code?

Comment: i know how to do in c# , but not in javascript

Comment: Then better give it a try and come back if you face any problems in the attempted code. Nobody here will write code for you.

Comment: this is my code .  now ple help me

Comment: there are multiple values in `ddl_fvr` for each value of the `ddl_customer` which value from those you want to select. Like if `ddl_fvr` select `ezhisai,raja`  then which one of the value get selected in the `ddl_customer`

Comment: if a selected in ddl_fvr, then selected value of ddl_customer  must be ezhisai,raja @Coder of Code

Comment: So what error you get when you run your code in browser ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#ddl_fvr").change(function() {
  $("#ddl_customer").find("option").attr("selected", false);
  var ary = $(this).val().split(",");
  for (var n = 0; n < ary.length; n++) {
    $("#ddl_customer").find("option[value=" + ary[n] + "]").attr("selected", true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddl_fvr">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="ezhisai,raja">ezhisai,raja</option>
  <option value="devi,kumar,sith">devi,kumar,sith</option>
  <option value="bala,raja">bala,raja</option>
  <option value="ezhisai,kumar,devi">ezhisai,kumar,devi</option>
</select>
<select id="ddl_customer" multiple="multiple" size="6">
  <option Value="ezhisai">ezhisai</option>
  <option Value="raja">raja</option>
  <option Value="devi">devi</option>
  <option Value="kumar">kumar</option>
  <option Value="sith">sith</option>
  <option Value="bala">bala</option>
</select>
```